# Assigning eventID while calling GL.IssuePluginEvent()

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins

While using the plugin in Unity, how to set the eventID during the call of GL.Issuepluginevent()

public static void IssuePluginEvent(IntPtr callback, int eventID);

I just want to know how to assign this eventID?

Specifically how to set this eventIDs while calling multiple plugins or issuing different callback (functions) defined in the native low-level plugin.

Comment: It's arbitrary so it's up to you to say this eventid is for this action and this one for the next action and so on...

Comment: so any integer value will work.GL.IssuePluginEvent(pluginfunc(), 123) should work right? But while doing this I am getting an error of E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler (Proxy.java:891). and can u also tell me what eventID 0 stands for?

Comment: Yes basically is that and I've already written a native c++ plug-in using arbitrary eventId without any problem I do think your problem is not related to the fact of calling GL.issuePluginEvent but it's might be related to what you plug-in is meant to do when it's called

Comment: in one plugin, to call a different function, we should use different eventID. Right? GL.IssuePluginEvent(pluginfunc1(), 123) & GL.IssuePluginEvent(pluginfunc1(), 124) for two funcs defind in some plugin.cpp?? and what the eventID 0 means?

Comment: Yes but you don't have to call GL.issuePluginEvent to call a cpp function this is just usable mostly for calling a function on the render thread and I don't know what eventid 0 means there is nothing about it the doc